# Allow button click through layer in Flash/ActionScript3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, events

I have the following layer structure in Flash:

- Spotlight - Has a transparent center area, is a bitmap symbol
- Button

How do I make `Button` clickable even though the `Spotlight` layer? I want to toggle the visibility of the `Spotlight` layer with the click of `Button` like the following code.

```
Button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICK, OnClick);

function OnClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
   Spotlight.visible = !Spotlight.visible;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While looking something else up, I found this.

```
Spotlight.mouseEnabled = false;
Spotlight.mouseChildren = false;
```